# Where is the journal stored?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I was reading through the link on [journaling-filesystems](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-journaling-filesystems/) and i would like to know where exactly is the journal stored in my Harddisk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ext3 and ext4 filesystems it's stored either in the journal inode (the default) or on a separate device, depending on the options passed to `mke2fs`.

Comment: Could you please explain me where the journal inode is?

Comment: Same place as all the other inodes: on your hard disk.

Comment: @Sen: data is stored on inodes. some inodes are made visible to the user via "names" (thats what you actually see). some inodes do not have a visible name. the journal inode is such an invisible one.